# Github - how to download hdf5 file?

Tags: github

How to download raw file in GitHub?
I am trying to [download a concrete (RAW) file](https://github.com/idealo/image-super-resolution/blob/master/weights/sample_weights/rrdn-C4-D3-G32-G032-T10-x4/Perceptual/rrdn-C4-D3-G32-G032-T10-x4_epoch299.hdf5).
The GitHub reports size 16.7 MB (see screenshot bellow), when clicked to RAW it only displays text containing few bytes.

Screen 
[image]

Comment: The file has been uploaded using git lfs. It is only a pointer file.

Comment: There's probably an URL you can request it from somewhere under `https://github.com/idealo/image-super-resolution.git/info/lfs/objects/`, but I don't know how to construct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git-lfs` to download content from this pointer files.

1. Install `git-lfs`, for mac use `brew install git-lfs`.
2. Clone the repo.
3. Run the command `git lfs pull`.

Reference : [git-cloning-giving-pointer-file](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/455)

Comment: The repo should be cloned before this.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this particular problem can be to download the files from this repository
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cJLPgGfEuFAQzBKbXQtSGXxLXssw1D9f

Anyway, if there is any way how to download HDF5 files from github, it would be very useful.